# How do i refer a click on first <li> to the first index in another array, and so on

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i'm currently doing a assignment on creating contacts and then retrieving the infos in another page. I have this page where a list of `<li>` of contacts that has been created will be shown. I am stuck at this point where when i click on this certain li that contains a value from one of the array elements(example surname), i can display full details of the other parameters in that index(name, gender..etc)

I have this array where i store contacts in it
example:

```
var contactArr;
```

a function to store the values from form

```
function Profile(input_1, input_2, input_3, input_4){
    this.input_1 = input_1;
    this.input_2 = input_2;
    this.input_3 = input_3;
    this.input_4 = input_4;
    }
```

each time someone filled up the form, 
i will push the infos into the array

```
contactArr.push(new Profile(input1, input2, input3, input4);
```

then when i access the page to view my existing contact i have sorted out the contacts Arr to make it in alphabetically form in terms of name
so we can assume 
contactArr have the following index-elements

```
[0] chow, Anisia, male
[1] tan, Beth, female
[2] ong, Crystal, female
```

then it will append it with `<li>` showing only the input2 which is the names

```
<li> Anisia </li>
<li> Beth </li>
<li> Crystal </li>
```

I have another div in the page.

So now the problem is when i click on the first `<li>` i want it to show the other details such as surname and gender on the `<div>` but i don't know the way to exactly do it despite searching online for reference.

My logic is that since i have sorted the contacts array in alphabetically forms. I can assume that the 1st li == first index of array 2nd li = 2nd index of array. I don't know how i can bind them together.

this is what i have so far

```
    $(contactArr).each(function(){
        $("#li").append('<li class="li">' + (this.input2) + '></li>');


        $(".li").click(function(){ 
         $("#contact-surname").text("Surname is " + this.input1);
         $("#contact-name").text("Name is " + this.input2);
         $("#contact-gender").text("Gender is " + this.input3);
        });
    });
```

example

```
$("#contact-surname").text("Surname is " + this.input1);
```

as my click function is nested in .each function, idk how to make the nested function this.name to refer to the contactArr[0].name,

Maybe some short tips and logics can be provided to advance on as i am quite confused with what i am doing or a short example of how i can bind the clicked li to the corresponding array elements that i can call out will do so i can learn from it. Thanks!

Comment: Put a data attribute on the LI mapping it to the ID in your database, when they click an item read the data off the element. `<li data-id="0"> Anisia </li>`

Comment: I can smell the flavour of ***event data*** missing in your code.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide jsffiddle

Comment: oh so using data-id="0" solve it? so if it's data-id="2" refers to the 3rd index of the array corresponding on where it retrieve the name Anisia am i right? i'll research on data-id while waiting for confirmation! thanks

Comment: @user3686746 That's the basic idea, rather than hoping that your list remains continuous, or no data get's deleted you use something that can't change(normally an ID in a database or a unique ID). `$(this).data('id')` will get the ID off the `li` in your onclick event, and you'll be able to use it to look up your data attached to it without worrying about the consistency of the front end ordering and possible missing/added data.

Comment: tell me if i'm wrong, so i do something like this
$("#li").append('<li class="li" data-id="0">' + (this.input2) + '></li>');

to call out i will be using

alert($(this).data("0").input1?

I'm not really that good at programming so sorry if i am still confused with what i'm doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the fact that you do have the array `contactArr`, which contains all the necessary information, I would split the process of creating the `<li>`s and its `.click()` events into *two* steps.

---

**First Step:** Creating the `<li>`s

```
$(contactArr).each(function (index) {
    $('#contactSurnameList').append('<li id="' + index + '" class="contactSurnameLi">' + this.input_2 + '</li>');
});
```

Regarding your question in the comments, I added this **alternative** to show how you could use `value` instead of `this`:

```
$(contactArr).each(function (index,value) {
    $('#contactSurnameList').append('<li id="' + index + '" class="contactSurnameLi">' + value.input_2 + '</li>');
});
```

With this code you create for *[each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)* entry in your `contactArr` a `<li>` which has the `contactArr index` as ID. By doing so, you are able to link each `<li>` with a specific entry in your `contactArr`.

Based on your statement:

> *"My logic is that since i have sorted the contacts array in alphabetically forms. I can assume that the 1st li == first index of array 2nd li = 2nd index of array."*

If this assumption is not valid (any more), I suggest that you create your `contactArr` as an [associative Array](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html#link4) and give each `Profile` a unique identifier (e.g. an ongoing number,..). By doing so, you can link the `<li>`s and your array entries based on this unique identifier, for example with the help of [indexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp).

---

**Second Step:** Bind the `.click()` event to each `<li>`

```
$('.contactSurnameLi').click(function () {
    var clickedProfil = contactArr[$(this).attr('id')];
    $("#contact-surname").html('Surname is <b>' + clickedProfil.input_1 + '</b>');
    $("#contact-name").html('First name is <b>' + clickedProfil.input_2 + '</b>');
    $("#contact-gender").html('Gender is <b>' + clickedProfil.input_3 + '</b>');
});
```

With this code, you bind a `.click()` event to each of your `<li>`s. When a `<li>` is clicked, its `ID` will be extracted and the linked entry in your `contactArr` is loaded. Then you can just fill up your detailed information `<div>` with the detailed information.

---

**Advantages:**

- By doing so, the code is far more modular and you can just add as many entries to your `contactAr` as you like. It still will work.
- Furthermore, you do have just *one* `.click()` event, which you can change when neccessary and it will be applied to all your `<li>`s.

---

**Working Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/skJ7E/3/

---

**One problem with your code:** `$('.li').click(...)`

In your code, you are executing the `$('.li').click(...)` code within the `each` function. The problem here is, that you are defining the click event *multiple times* (as many times as your each loop runs through). This is not necessary, as the code `$('.li').click(...)` function defines the `.click()` event for **all** elements matching the jQuery selector `$('.li')` (all elements with the class `li`). So basically, you are binding the `.click()` event to your `<li>`s multiple times, each time with the same function inside.

Comment: Hey firstly thanks to you, although i don't have enough reputation to upvote you since i'm new but i'm glad you helped. i just saw through ur fiddle and i know that this will solve my issues. I am going to edit my code in reference to how you do it. I have seen your codes to understand briefly on how it works i want to point out the parts where i'm not sure if it's correct on my understanding and hope you can correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: I'm not clear about function(index, value);
does it mean that each time you loop through the .each loop, the index will become 1,2,3..etc
so when you append you add the current loop index value into the id of the <li> to create a unique id to refer to? Then i see the use of index but i don't see any thing relate to the 'value' you put inside function()..

lastly it's this
var clickedProfil = contactArr[$(this).attr('id')];
the part .attri(id') is trying to get the (this) which is the <li> click and refer the id from it right? 

Thanks again! You solved my 4 hours dilemma

Comment: @user3686746 Hey, I'm glad I could help. Regarding the `each(function(index))` question, you are right. Each time it loops through, the index becomes the current processed entry's index; but be careful, they are *zero-based* (starting at 0). This is how I create a unique id to refer to. I mistakenly left the `value` inside the function, it contains the value of the currently processed array entry (in your case each `Profile`), but I don't use it and updated my jsfiddle, thanks! Second question: You're right again, the `$(this).attr('id')` retrieves the `ID` of the clicked `<li>`.

Comment: I also updated my answer regarding your first question.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my understanding on this noobish questions haha, now i can continue with my work!

Comment: Now i can click on a <li> and it will show the details, i added a modify option so you can input a new surname and update it. I used clickedProfile.surname = $("input[name=contact-surname]").val(); to edit the .surname element in the array. Works fine but once i create a new contact, the updated changes change back to the default values. It only reverts whenever i create a new contact. is it because i edited clickedprofile but it wasn't a precise one? Since clickprofile = contactarray, i'm assuming editing clickprofile == editing contactarray. Thanks for reading my question

Comment: Please do open a new question, as the comment section is not made for further debugging your code.